# Stop generating URLs for German, Russia and French after reindexing catalog_url rewrites

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite

Can anyone please let me know how to stop generating urls for German, Russian and French stores after reindexing catalog_url. I tried disabliing stores in the system --> admin --> Manage Stores but still urls are generating for those stores. please help me in this. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url rewrites are refreshed by the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url::refreshRewrites()`.
You can rewrite this model and change the method to reindex only the enabled stores.
Something like this:

```
public function refreshRewrites($storeId = null)
{
    if (is_null($storeId)) {
        foreach ($this->getStores() as $store) {
            if ($store->getIsActive()) {
                $this->refreshRewrites($store->getId());
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    $this->clearStoreInvalidRewrites($storeId);
    $this->refreshCategoryRewrite($this->getStores($storeId)->getRootCategoryId(), $storeId, false);
    $this->refreshProductRewrites($storeId);
    $this->getResource()->clearCategoryProduct($storeId);

    return $this;
}
```